# Search multiple keywords in log file line and return error string is all found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create this program which opens up a .gz file and looks for multiple exceptions.  It was working when I just used one exception.  But I am now trying to get multiple exceptions, and it is not working.

Can anyone help?

```
import gzip
with gzip.open((raw_input("Enter File Name :")), 'r') as f:
     x1 = ['REBINFO', 'cocaLc']
     y1 = [False, False]
     x2 = ['dispute', 'peer', 'while', 'priority']
     y2 = [False, False, False, False]
     x3 = ['task cocaLc ASSERT failed', 'fhAssert', 'REBINFO', 'HARDREBOOT', '09.']
     y3 = [False, False, False, False, False]
     for line in f:
         for i in range(0, len(x1)):
             if (x1, x2, x3) [i] in line: #loop through x1, x2, x3 using index numbers
                 y1[i] = True
                 y2[i] = True
                 y3[i] = True

 if all(y1): #if every search string was detected, every value in y1 should be true
     print "Exception Found : " + "task cocaLc Requested reboot"
 if all(y2): #if every search string was detected, every value in y2 should be true
     print "\nException Found : " + "task tAlrmL1 Keep alive failed"
 if all(y3): #if every search string was detected, every value in y3 should be true
     print "\nException Found : task cocaLc ASSERT failed"
```

Comment: and what is your problem??

Comment: this program is not working, looking for some solution around the same logic which i'm using, thanks for the help Jean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: The problem in your question is the "it is not working", which is to broad. You need to describe what happens that you don't want and what you wish it happened.

Comment: Please explain, do you get a run-time error? Can you give a reproducible example? What output do you expect and what do you get? What is the input to your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code meets your problem statement.  Two key changes from your code.

1. Put error message and keywords to search for together in the same data structure.
2. Loop over the data structure and directly determine if all keywords are present, and if not store the error message for later display

Please note: I did not actually test this code, as I had no sample data.

**Code:**

```
import gzip

errors_to_find = (
    ('task cocaLc Requested reboot', 
     ('REBINFO', 'cocaLc')),
    ('task tAlrmL1 Keep alive failed',
     ('dispute', 'peer', 'while', 'priority')),
    ('task cocaLc ASSERT failed', 
     ('fhAssert', 'REBINFO', 'HARDREBOOT')),
)

found_exc = []
with gzip.open((raw_input("Enter File Name :")), 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for msg, key_words in errors_to_find:

            # for each keyword, test if it is in line 
            if sum([kw in line for kw in key_words]) == len(key_words):
                found_exc.append(msg)

for msg in found_exc:
    print "Exception Found : %s" % msg
```

Comment: Stephen .... thanks for the help, actually i want to keep the error message separately, i want to print out  separate statement for separate errors. Example : x1 = ['REBINFO', 'cocaLc'], x1 represents these two exceptions and if these both are present than i would like to print the "defect" number, which i've not mentioned here due to our nature of our business, but that defect will be unique. same for x2 = ['dispute', 'peer', 'while', 'priority'], if all the strings in variable x2 present in the file than there will be another unique defect which needs to print.

Comment: This is exactly why you need the messages and the keywords associated with them in the same data structure.  This will allow much easier maintenance over time as the keywords and associated messages change.